# Can oversleeping be harmful to overall health?

Tags: sleep, lifestyle, sleep-cycles, fatigue, physiology

Is it worse than undersleeping, especially for healthy development? Does it have any benefits? I would like to know both physical and mental effects (or diseases?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Studies have linked oversleeping with

- Cognitive impairment
- Depression
- Increased inflammation
- Increased pain
- Impaired fertility
- Higher risk of obesity
- Higher risk of diabetes
- Higher risk of heart disease
- Higher risk of stroke
- Higher all-cause mortality

You can find the detailed article here: http://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/guide/physical-side-effects-oversleeping#1

Comment: I feel like little effort went into this, but I guess it was what I was looking for.

Comment: @Adamawesome4 Please have a [look at this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biphasic_and_polyphasic_sleep), you might find this interesting.

Comment: I'd love to know which way the cause-and-effect relationship goes with these.